# Does RSA key pairs expires in Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

Our application is migrating to Docusign's JWT authentication. For that we should generate RSA key pairs.

1. Does RSA key pairs expire?
2. Does Docusign providing Java SDK to generate RSA key pairs or is it manual only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The RSA keypairs won't expire, you are free to have your own rotation cycle, however. Invalidating them is easy through the UI. You can upload your own generated RSA keys or use the auto-generation function available.
2. You can create and upload RSA pairs only through the website from the Apps and Keys page. It is currently not possible to create/upload them via the APIs or SDKs

Comment: Do you need to give consent all over again whenever the RSA key pairs rotate?

Comment: No, unless you're requesting new scopes. You will need to pass the new key in the requestJWTUserToken method